# Flutter : how to change theme color of button in floating action button?

Tags: flutter, button, background-color, flutter-animation

**1. Question background**

I want to change the background color of button, keeping the original color of icon. In my program, my button color is blue. Since I wanted to remove the blue color, I tried several ways. But everything didn't work.

**2. What I already tried**

1. theme : ThemeData

   theme: ThemeData(
   colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
   primary : Colors.lime,
   ),
   ),
2. backgroundColor : Theme.of()

   backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

(etc using theme color modification)

**3. My code and Result**

```
      body : Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.lime[200],
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount :name.length,
            itemBuilder: (c,i){
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: ListTile(
                 leading: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
                  title : Text(name[i]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
            primary : Colors.lime,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
            //designate the developer made function into specific name
            return DialogUI(usingaddOne:addOne, usingaddString : addString);
          });
        },
        child : const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, ,),
      ),
    );}
}
```

> > Result
> > [image: what i didn't expected : lime colored icon]

**4. Question**

I want to change the button with lime (or red) background color with the original color of icon. Or just remove the blue color. Is there any other way that i've not tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right, just in the theme there is an attribute like this :

```
static ThemeData get lightTheme {
    return ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.white, // your main color app
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      fontFamily: 'Segoe',

      // * FLOATING ACTION BUTTON THEME
      floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
        elevation: 2, // elevation
        backgroundColor: Colors.lime, // the background color
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This **static ThemeData variable** (create it in other class, i named *AppTheme*), you can write it in your **main.dart** in the **MaterialApp** like this :

```
 return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: AppTheme.lightTheme, // here
    initialRoute: PageNames.home,
 );
```

And in your **FloatingActionButton**, you don't have to do any other thing

```
 FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () => onAction(),
    child: Icon(
       Icons.add,
       color: Colors.white,
    ),
 ),
```

In other words, delete the theme in your **FloatingActionButton** Widget and put it in your **MaterialApp**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

- Define the color you want to use in theme:

  ```
  floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
  ),
  ```
- Set `backgroundColor` property in `FloatingActionButton`:

  ```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
  ```